# Download rtmpe videos from youtube?

Tags: youtube, video-streaming

I need to download a video from the youtube which is of type "rtmpe".
Is there any way to download the video by any means?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these:

- [How to download flash video RTMP/RTMPE streams using free
  software](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/311893-How-to-download-flash-video-RTMP-RTMPE-streams-using-free-software)
- [RTMPDump](http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/)

I could download RTMPE videos by using RTMPDump.

Comment: Does it means that RTMPE only provides end to end security for the contents and there is no way to limit of user accesses to the shared media?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure. But I've downloaded RTMPE videos from [InfoQ](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/) by using RTMPDump. I've not tested with [youtube.com](https://www.youtube.com/) though.